# Parameters being ignored with Doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I have a bunch of filters containing parameters that I would want to be included in my query using the QueryBuilder from Doctrine.

Here is my code :

```
$qb=  $em->createQueryBuilder();
$query_qb = $qb
     ->from('padmaxResilieBundle:Subscriber','s')
     ->leftjoin('s.terminationPaper','l')
     // ...
     ->leftjoin('c.cancelreasons','cr');

    if ($filters) {
        foreach ($filters as $value) {
            $query_qb->andWhere($value);
        }
    }

    $query_qb->setParameters($this->paramsMap);

     $total = $query_qb->addSelect('COUNT(DISTINCT s)')
         ->getQuery()
         ->getResult();
```

Each element of the array $filters are string with 1 or more occurences of a parameter, ex :

```
$filters = array(
    0 => "s.lastname LIKE '%:param1%' OR s.firstname LIKE '%:param1%'"
    1 => "c.contractNumber LIKE '%:param2%'"
    // ...
)
```

The parameter identifier is different for each filter and is referenced in the propertie paramMap like :

```
$this->paramMap = array(
    "param1" => "my_value",
    "param2" => "hello",
    // ...
)
```

I'm assured that both the filter array and the paramMap are correct and references each other but I always got the error :

```
Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

I can't figure what I'm doing wrong, any ideas ?

Comment: I'm 100% sure that there is a mismatch between `$filters` and `$this->paramMap`. You can easily debug this if you display the DQL string (`echo $query_qb->getQuery()->getDQL()`) and your parameter list (`dump($query_qb->getQuery()->getParameters()`)

Comment: I have a step-by-step debugger and no, it's matching. The parameters are returned by getParameters() with the corrects value. And I still have the error...

Comment: Can you show values stored in `$filters` and `$this->paramMap`?

Comment: I have edited my post for more clarity, these were actual values.

Comment: Look at doctrine tab in symfony toolbar, is there the query with applied parameters already visible?

Comment: Could you show us results of two dumps suggested by @Raphaël anyway ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use parameters in strings like you are doing:

```
"c.contractNumber LIKE '%:param2%'"
```

You need to put the % characters in your parameters:

```
$filters = array(
    0 => "s.lastname LIKE :param1 OR s.firstname LIKE :param1"
    1 => "c.contractNumber LIKE :param2"
    // ...
)

$this->paramMap = array(
    "param1" => "%my_value%",
    "param2" => "%hello%",
    // ...
)
```